# How to preload the WPF runtime engine or how to reduce its loading time?

Tags: c#, wpf, com, runtime

we have a legacy application done in VB6. When we add new windows to this application we create them with WPF and we expose a COM interface to open it from VB6. The problem is that the first time a WPF window is opened it takes a while as the system needs to load the WPF run-time.

Is there a way to  load the run-time in background so the user does not has to wait when opening the window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- Create hidden WPF windows when VB6 application starts, so WPF will load while user will do something else in application.
- If it will not work with hidden window, you still can create WPF window with positon like new Point(10000, 10000), and select to not show this window in taskbar, so this hidden WPF window will force .NET to load WPF engine.

So, you can create invisible WPF window in background when application starts, and user will not have to wait later.

Comment: I was thinking more on something like manually loading the libraries with LoadLibrary or something like that ...

Comment: @SoMos: That won't do anything at all.

Comment: @Joshua: If the application has the libraries already loaded in memory everything will be faster right?

Comment: SoMoS: Hardly. Most of the disk blocks won't even get paged in when loading .NET components with LoadLibrary. Also,you have to do the GAC resolution manually or it will blow up in your face at some point down the line.

Comment: @SoMoS It is .NET Framework, so LoadLibrary will not help here. It uses a very different strategy from native Windows code, even if you loaded assembly with Assembly.Load method (.NET replacement for LoadLibrary), it doesn't mean that loaded assembly is initialized, it is just loaded in memory. The only way to force it to initialize beforehand is to call any methods on this assembly.

Comment: @ToAll: I'm talking about loading the RUNTIME of WPF / Framework, not the .Net assemblies of my application which are comparatively small.

Comment: You can load .NET, create AppDomain and load any assembly manually with unmanaged API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380850.aspx (ICLRRuntimeHost::Start will load .NET in process explicitly). However, it is not easy solution.